# How to create a "on" array from a "switch on" array and "switch off" array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I have two arrays representing timeseries, one describing when a switch turns on, and the other when the switch turns off. At the end, I want a status array describing when the object was on or off.

```
switchOn_arr = [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0]
switchOff_arr= [1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0]
isLightOn_arr= [0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0]
```

The switch can be turned on even if the object is already on, The switch can be turned off even if the object is already off.
How to do this in an efficient manner in javascript?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stackoverflow exists to answer specific questions and not to write your code for you.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @Thomas it won't work because you need to use the previous value. Notice that there are a few (0, 0, 1) pairs and right at the end a (0, 0, 0) pair.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it. It iterates the array with on switches, grabs the off switches, act on the light, pushes the resulted value in the result array and returns the light status so it can re-used as previous light value in the next reduce step.

```js
const onArr = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0];
const offArr = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0];
const lightArr = [];
onArr.reduce((prevLight, switchOn, idx) => {
    let light = prevLight, switchOff = offArr[idx];
    light = light || switchOn; // maybe turn on the light
    light = light && !switchOff ? 1 : 0; // keep the light as it is if it wasn't switched off
    lightArr.push(light); // push to results array
    return light; // save light for next reduce iteration
}, 0); // by default, light is turned off
console.log(lightArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

as long as it's all ones and zeroes, or `true` and `false` you can do simple bit-operations:

basically `isOn = (isOn or switchOn) and not switchOff`

```js
const switchOn_arr = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0];
const switchOff_arr= [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0];

let isOn = 0;
const isLightOn_arr = switchOn_arr.map((switchOn,i) => isOn = (isOn | switchOn) & !switchOff_arr[i]);

console.log("on ", switchOn_arr.join(" "));
console.log("off", switchOff_arr.join(" "));
console.log("-> ", isLightOn_arr.join(" "));
```